# Redirect to root url in AJAX

Tags: django, django-ajax-selects

I'm looking for a way to start URL with ('') instead of ('search/') in AJAX request. I can workaround this problem simply add new path in URL dispatcher with `path('search/email_add/<int:pk>/', views.email_add, name="email_add_from_search")` but it's not a DRY method and a RedirectView not satisfy me.

It works properly when I'm using add-phone.js script while in root URL.

Error `Not Found: /search/email_add/41/` while using script in ('search/') URL

***Ajax Request***

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'email_add/'+person_id+'/',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'email': email,
                },
                error: function(result){},
                success: function(result){},
```

***urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.contact_list, name="contact_list"), # GET
    path('add/', views.contact_add, name="contact_add"), # POST
    path('search/', views.contact_search, name="contact_search"), # GET
    path('delete/<int:pk>/',  views.contact_detail, name="contact_delete"), # DELETE
    path('edit/<int:pk>/',  views.contact_detail, name="contact_edit"), # POST
    path('phone_add/<int:pk>/', views.phone_add, name="phone_add"), # POST
    path('email_add/<int:pk>/', views.email_add, name="email_add"), # POST
    # path('search/phone_add/<int:pk>/', views.phone_add, name="phone_add_from_search"),
    # path('search/email_add/<int:pk>/', views.email_add, name="email_add_from_search"),

]
```

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to `/search/email_add/41/` when you send a post request to `/phone_add/41/` end-point?

Comment: This isn't clear. Do you simply want the Ajax to post to "/phone_add/<id>"? In which case why don't you do that, by including a leading slash?

Comment: Sorry guys, my fault. I copied wrong code. Just edited.

Comment: OK but the same question applies. Why don't you simply do `url: '/email_add/'+person_id+'/',`

Comment: @PankajSharma No. The problem was with a leading slash as DanielRoseman mentioned before. Issue solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your javascript this `url: 'email_add/'+person_id+'/'` is accessing a relative url.  So if you're in url `http://my-web-site/some/path` it will take you to `http://my-web-site/some/path/email_add/id/`

I think you want the `http://my-web-site/email_add/id/` which means you need `url: '/email_add/'+person_id+'/'`

Comment: Yep, the problem was with a leading slash. DanielRoseman gave me an solution in comment, but  when you wrote this answer I only then saw where the error lies.

Comment: I realised Daniel had given you the answer.  I didn't know if you understood it